# How to change python list returns from letters to numbers

Tags: python-3.x

How can I return where something is located on a list? For example, if you have List = [a, b, c] and the user inputs c the program should return 2.  How can I code this though?

Comment: Try `[a, b, c].index(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> my_list = ["a", "b", "c"]

> my_list.index("c")
2
```